# Android push notification device to device

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I want to make push notification without using GCM for device to device.I want to send information to any device using contact number.I also tried to look for it but couldn't find. I might be wrong but I must want to send push notification device device without using Google Cloud Messaging and as an when receive the notification on another device and open the notification , it should be open in an Activity.Can someone help me please.Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: what is a contact number?do you mean phone number?

Comment: @aorlando:- Yes ,Because in my app user just enter the name , product and his contact number , so that i can push the notification on his device via contact number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To realize this app I think you should not confuse Android Notification with GCM push Notification. What you see in the android status bar are Android notification and you can show it using the Notification Builder class:

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```

So I think you can send a text message using Android api as example from the web:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And you do not need to use GCM push notification

to open the an activity from notification you can use:

```
NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notif = new Notification(icon, mess, when);

Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);

notifIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifIntent, 0);

notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, mess, intent);
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notifManager.notify(0, notif);
```

Comment: :- Thanks for the reply , But my big issue is when user receives the notification and that time i want to open in an Activity.

Comment: I can not post here a complete sampl but the web is full of this kind of stuff: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/android-notifications-example/

Comment: :- I have tried examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/ this example but notification does not send to another device.Even also i have change the line of // Creates an implicit intent
112
      Intent resultIntent = new Intent("com.example.javacodegeeks.TEL_INTENT",
113
              Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
114
      resultIntent.putExtra("from", "javacodegeeks");